# Clojure function behaving differently than identical inline code?

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

I have a function that returns another function, cons-then-eval-fn:

```
(defn cons-then-eval-fn [x]
  (fn [& e] (cons x (eval e))))
```

From that, I define two instances of this concept, one using cons-then-eval-fn, the other doing the same thing but with inlined code:

```
(def zero-a (cons-then-eval-fn 0))
(def zero-b (fn [& e] (cons 0 (eval e))))
```

With some arguments, these two functions behave identically (as I would expect):

```
(zero-a) => (0)
(zero-b) => (0)
(zero-a identity []) => (0)
(zero-b identity []) => (0)
```

But with these arguments, I see differing behavior:

```
(zero-b zero-b identity []) => (0 0)
(zero-a zero-a identity []) =>
   IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found
```

Can anyone please help me understand why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

You must not eval function objects. eval is for symbols, lists, and so on: source code to be fed to the compiler. An already-compiled function object is an invalid argument to eval; it happens to work in some cases and not in others (specifically, for closures it fails and for functions with no captured scope it works, but this is not guaranteed).